# How to create efficient database for routing?

Tags: routing, database, sqlite

I created a database of many important features and locations of my city, and I want to find shortest/fastest path between two locations. Now, I'm calculating the route by using the A* algorithm in Java for Android device, but it takes too much time to calculate and draw a simple route.

Is there any efficient way to store and retrieve the road data from database for route calculation?

Comment: A* tends to be fast. Did you profile your code? Can you post the results?

Comment: Is your database a PostGIS/pgRouting database (given the tag that you applied to it) or something else?

Comment: I am using SQLite Database

Comment: Have you considered using the spatialite routing code? It implements both A* and Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the normal solution to pre-calculate a route index? That's what OSRM does: https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/wiki/Running-OSRM

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Open Source routing software for Android:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Mobile_Device_software

They normally use format similar to a graph database. One city should be even possible in-memory on Android (at least with graphhopper). But for bigger sizes you'll need to implement a proper storage solution.